# php how to sort the values in multiple arrays in the order of frequency

Tags: php, sorting

I have an array containing multiple arrays like

```
$A = array();
$A[0] = array("1","2","3","4","5");
$A[1] = array("1","6","7","8");
$A[2] = array("0","1","3");
```

I want to sort the values in multiple arrays in the order of frequency and put them into another array let's say $B.

The values in $B is "1","1","1","3","3","0","2","4","5","6","7","8".

Comment: Is flatMap available in php? if it is you can simple flatMap(A) and then sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
$A = array();
$A[0] = array("1","2","3","4","5");
$A[1] = array("1","6","7","8");
$A[2] = array("0","1","3");

//Merging above array in to one array
$merged = array_values(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $A));
//Getting occurrence count
$counts = array_count_values($merged);
//Sort by count
arsort($counts);

//Adding to required array
$B = array();
foreach ($counts as $k => $v)
 for($i=1;$i<=$v;$i++)
  $B[] = $k;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($B);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 8
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 5
    [9] => 2
    [10] => 4
    [11] => 6
)
```

Comment: $merged = array_values(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $A)); and $merged = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $A); are the same?

Answer (score 0):

1. First merge all arrays

   $array1    = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);

   $array2    = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);

   $resultado = array_merge($array1, $array2);

see -> http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php

2. Second sort the big array

   arsort($resultado );

   see -> http://php.net/manual/es/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash table to count the frequency of each number, and then store them in the decreasing order of frequency in array `$B`, like this:

```
$hash_table = array();
foreach($A as $array){
    foreach($array as $value){
        if(empty($hash_table[$value])){
            $hash_table[$value] = 1;
        }else{
            $hash_table[$value] += 1;
        }
    }
}
arsort($hash_table);

$B = array();
foreach($hash_table as $key => $value){
    for($i = 0; $i < $value; ++$i){
        $B[] = $key;
    }
}

var_dump($B);  // to see the contents of array $B
```

Answer (score 0):

If order of same occurance count items isn't important, you can use:

```
// Merge all arrays
$counts = array_count_values(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $A));

// Sort by occurance
arsort($counts);

// Add [value] to new array [occurance] times
$B = array();
array_walk($counts, function($occurances, $value) use (&$B){
    for($i=0;$i<$occurances;$i++) $B[] = $value;
});
echo implode(',', $B);
```

**Output**

`1,1,1,3,3,0,8,7,5,2,4,6`

Answer (score 0):

```
Array print in order of count and index:

$temp = array();

foreach($A as $b){
    foreach($b as $c){
        if(isset($tmep[$c])){
            $tmep[$c]++;
        }else{
            $tmep[$c] = 1;
        }
    }
}

function SortArrayByKeyThanValue (&$pArray, $pSortMethodForKey = SORT_ASC, $pSortMethodForValue = SORT_DESC){
    # check user input: sorting is not necessary
    if (count($pArray) < 2)
        return;

    # define $k and $v as array_multisort() needs real variables, as user input is put by reference
    $k = array_keys  ($pArray);
    $v = array_values($pArray);

    array_multisort(
        $v, $pSortMethodForValue,
        $k, $pSortMethodForKey
    );
    $pArray = array_combine($k, $v);
}

SortArrayByKeyThanValue($tmep); 

$B = array();
array_walk($tmep, function($occurances, $value) use (&$B){
    for($i=0;$i<$occurances;$i++) $B[] = $value;
});

echo implode(',', $B);
```